# unable to call self invoking function

Tags: javascript

i am trying to call self invoking function but it doesn't seem to work, as you can see code below i am able to alert (test) but not when it is called upon another function. Please advise - Thank you

```
var test = (function(a,b){
       return a*b;
           })(4,5);

function myFunc() {};

alert(test); // working
alert(test.call(myFunc, 10,5)); // not working
```

Comment: How do you expect to call a **self invoking** function, when the function is invoked immediately and returns a number based on parameters that are hardcoded in? `test` contains the number 20 because it is invoked immediately. Is there a reason you want to use a self invoking function here?

Comment: `test` is not a function, thus it has no `call` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An immediately invoking function is one that executes right when the script is loaded. In your example, the function next to test is executed right away, and it returns a value of 20.

I have a feeling what you really want is something like this:

```
var test = (function()
{
    var a = 4,
        b = 5;

    return function()
    {
        return a*b;
    }
}());
```

So in what I wrote above, test will NOT be set to 20. Instead, it'll be set to a function that multiplies `a` against `b` and returns 20.  Why? Cause when I immediately invoke the function, it's not returning the actual value; it's returning yet another function, and that function then returns the actual value that I'm trying to calculate.

Comment: Thanks Kinsho for looking into it, i think you are using closures to simply what i was after. Actually i was more trying to understand .call() and trying to call on self invoked function but i think it's not the right way as it immediately calculates the results of function and assign to a variable Test.

    function test(a,b){
 return a*b;
            };

    function myFunc(){}
    alert(test(2,10));
    alert(test.call(myFunc, 10,5))

Answer (score 2):

You are evaluating the function at line 0, and assigning the return value "20" to `test`. Since 20 is a number, not a function, you can't call it. Try instead:

```
var test = function(a,b){
  return a*b;
};
alert(test(4,5));
alert(test(10,5));
```

Comment: Thanks jsha - i got your point. Can you give me an example code of calling a self invoked function via another function or is it not possible.